# Full access control for file using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have a requirement to package the XML Files to ExE;

I’m using NSIS Script package. But I have query on the same ExE I have used default installation path `C:/XML-Data/` for XML package.

I have configuration fie `xmlpathconfiguration.conf` in the same XML Package and which will be in this location `< C:/XML-Data/xmlpathconfiguration.conf>`

But my doubt is `xmlpathconfiguration.conf` user is unable to change the configuration inputs in the file.

Please let me know how to package it, So that user and Admin can edit the inputs based on there requirement
Present Usage for packaging

File `..\..\xmlpathconfiguration.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the ACL of a file you have to use the [AccessControl plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in):

```
SetOutPath $InstDir
File "....\xmlpathconfiguration.conf"
AccessControl::GrantOnFile  "$INSTDIR\xmlpathconfiguration.conf" "(WD)" "FullAccess" ; You should consider using "GenericRead + GenericWrite" instead...
```

Comment: Anders,

Thanks for the reply,
I did the same as per your suggestion but still i was facing issue

NSIS ver 2.4.6
MSVC 2008
Code:
SetOutPath: "$InstDir"
File: "xmlPathConfiguration.conf" 248 bytes
Invalid command: AccessControl::GrantOnFile
Error in script "xml_data_package.nsi" on line 387 -- aborting creation process
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '\NSIS\makensis.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Comment: Thanks Anders
It meet my expectation and logic is working fine
I have download the plugin from http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File:AccessControl.zip